# service.error() or service.setWarning() in Maximo automation javascript does not show popup on UI

Tags: javascript, service, automation, popup, maximo

I am trying to create an automation script (action launch point, trigger by a button on UI) for Maximo using javascript to do some data validation then show popup if there is invalid data.

1. I try to call service.setWarning() but the script still process instead of showing a warning message, if I do some UI interaction later, that warning message randomly display later.
2. Then I try the service.error() which should show an error message similar to the exception message in Maximo, the script does stop running but there is no popup message.
3. If I check systemError.log, I can see both the warning and error message displayed in the log?

So what is causing this and how can I make it behave correctly?

EDIT1: here is the script, I already setup the message in database configuration (messagegroup RFQ, messagekey 2VENDORS):

```
    load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");
importPackage(Packages.psdi.security);
importPackage(Packages.psdi.mbo);
importPackage(Packages.psdi.server);

var mxServer = MXServer.getMXServer();
var userInfo = mxServer.getSystemUserInfo();

var rfqLineSet = mbo.getMboSet("RFQLINE");
var totalCost = 0;
var current_datetime = new Date();
var today = current_datetime.toISOString();

for(var currMbo=rfqLineSet.moveFirst(); currMbo!=null; currMbo=rfqLineSet.moveNext()) { 
    totalCost = totalCost + currMbo.getDouble("LINECOST");
}

if (totalCost < 50000) {
    var rfqVendorSet = mbo.getMboSet("RFQVENDOR");
    
    if (rfqVendorSet.count() > 2) {
        service.error("RFQ","2VENDORS",null);
    }
}
```

Maximo version 7.6.1

EDIT2: I tried the service.yncerror("RFQ","2VENDORS",null); which should display a yes/no error popup message but same issue, it only appears in the systemError.log

EDIT3: I did some tests and found out that if I write the code in Jython then the popup works but not in Javascript. How can this be?

UPDATE: I moved all my scripts to use python instead of javascript, seems that Maximo works best with automation script written in python.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add your code and warnings/ errors to the question

Comment: Which Maximo version are you on?

Comment: I added the script and version in the question.

Comment: If you change the "service.error..." line to `throw MXApplicationException("RFQ", "2VENDORS");`, what happens? Do you still get your error only in the logs?

Answer (score 3):

"Warnings" in Maximo are some bits of data that just ride along with the MBO set. As a warning, they aren't supposed to stop execution, just let you know of something important, but they won't even do that on their own. You need to do something at some point to fetch the warnings from the set and display them. If you don't, Maximo will on its own for certain actions (usually for those actions that would include a warning Maximo itself added), but that probably isn't when you actually want it to be displayed. I have seen many people mix this up and not understand what these warnings are or how they actually work.

"Errors" are meant to be logic stopping messages. Something went wrong and the user needs to know about it before more logic runs. This sounds more like your use case. Errors are still meant to be a message to the user though, so you have to supply a message for the error method. You can't just put any string you want as your message in there though (well, you shouldn't) as that doesn't allow Maximo to translate the message or fill in message variables. It also means you have to change code whenever you want to change the message, instead of simply changing a configuration live. Instead you need to go to Database Configuration and add a new message in there. When you do that, you will create a message group and message key value for your message. Now when you call the error method, you will pass in that error group and error key as parameters. Maximo will take that, look it up in the message table and then display the message associated with that group and key for your configured language. It can also replace some special message variables at this time too, but that's a lesson for another time.

For example, you might go to Database Configuration and open the dialog for the messages and add a message of "The value you entered in the 'count' field is not a number. Please enter a number before continuing." and give it a message group of "MyCustomGrp" and a key of "NotANumber". Then in your code when you want to stop the code and display that message, you would call `service.error("MyCustomGrp", "NotANumber")`.

The other potential problem you could be having is that you do need to be running the code that throws the error in some way attached to the interactive user session. Generally, that's a given, but there are some things you could be doing that would cause your code to run separate from that interactive user session. If you are seeing your error message in the logs, then you have set that part up correctly and it likely means your code is not part of the interactive user session. This is where knowing the rest of your code is very important.

Comment: hi, I have added the script as requested, pls have a look, thank you.